# Python packages hash not matching whilst installing using pip

Tags: python, pip

I am using pip to install all my python packages but get error as shown in the trace below. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

```
usr@comp:~$ pip install flask
    Collecting flask
      Using cached Flask-0.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Collecting itsdangerous>=0.21 (from flask)
      Using cached itsdangerous-0.24.tar.gz
    Collecting click>=2.0 (from flask)
      Using cached click-6.6.tar.gz
    Collecting Werkzeug>=0.7 (from flask)
      Using cached Werkzeug-0.11.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.4 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from flask)
    Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): MarkupSafe in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Jinja2>=2.4->flask)
    THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
        Werkzeug>=0.7 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/a9/5e/41f791a3f380ec50f2c4c3ef1399d9ffce6b4fe9a7f305222f014cf4fe83/Werkzeug-0.11.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=c63a21eedce9504d223ed89358c4bdc9 (from flask):
        Expected md5 c63a21eedce9504d223ed89358c4bdc9
             Got        13a168aafcc43354b6c79ef44bb0dc71
```

Comment: Are you using a requirements file? This error suggests that you're using pip's hash checking mode and may be trying to upgrade a package's version without upgrading the hash first.

Comment: No I am not explicitly using a requirements file but pip is checking flaks' dependencies using its (flask) requirements file. How do I make the hash upgrades?

Comment: Thanks to your comment jonafato, I fount a question from 2013 that has a solution that worked for me. The solution is in the answer below

Comment: check my answer in [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38028170/installing-python-packages-have-issue-in-md5/40400414#40400414) ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does pip fail with bad md5 hash for package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025788/why-does-pip-fail-with-bad-md5-hash-for-package)

Comment: I got this error after installing tensorflow, uninstalling it, and then trying to reinstall it. The selected answer solves it for me!

Answer (score 91, accepted):

There is a similar problem ([Why does pip fail with bad md5 hash for package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16025788/why-does-pip-fail-with-bad-md5-hash-for-package)) from 2013 the solution that I tried that worked for me is this:

```bash
sudo pip install --no-cache-dir flask
```

given by attolee

Answer (score 41):

The problem here is the Python package was updated with new hash value while pip was trying to install the Python package using the old hash value cached in pip cache directory. This cache needs to be purge before the pip install attempt. So the full solution is:

```
python -m pip cache purge
python -m pip install <package>
```

Comment: When I try the command, I get the error: ERROR: pip cache commands can not function since cache is disabled. If cache is disabled, why am I getting the error? any idea?

Answer (score 19):

`--no-cache-dir`  did not work for me in raspberry pi 4 at first.

Found that the problem was due to unexpected network change/failure during pip installation

I had to download the broken `.whl` file manually with `wget`

and install it like below:
`sudo pip install scipy-1.3.0-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl`

followed by 
`sudo pip install --no-cache-dir keras`

Then it worked.

Comment: Using `--no-cache-dir` did not work for me. This did! But not sure what the real problem is though. Thanks for the instruction.

Comment: This fixed my problem also for me on a Raspberry Zero! `sudo` shouldn't be necessary in general though.

Answer (score 11):

You need to upgrade your pip into the newer version:

Using this command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

for Mac/Linux operating system and use

```
python -m pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

for Windows to update your pip. Then run your command

```
 pip install flask
```

Comment: Nice one, you forgot another dash before -upgrade:  `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 11):

Looks like a cache problem, the cached package is different from `REQUIREMENTS`.

Perhaps caused by last updates interruption.

I did this which fixed my problem:

```sh
rm ~/.cache/pip -rf
```

Answer (score 7):

In case you got this error while using pipenv try

```
$ pipenv --clear
$ pipenv lock
$ pipenv install
```

Answer (score 5):

First, try to upgrade your pip then install the library:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

If it didn't work, just try to install it without the cache:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir the_library_name
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue for a different module. It was caused by network failure. My fix was nothing complex but another attempt at installing it and it worked.

Comment: Yes, I had same issue which by changing network type, it solved.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me:

```
    $ source .venv/Scripts/activate
    $ python -m pip install --upgrade pip
    $ python -m pip install <package> --no-cache-dir
```

If it does not work for some packages try to do this before the previous steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69668918/17596747

Then do the first 3 steps again.

UPD. Also maybe the problem is in VPN. Try to turn off/turn on VPN and see if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

`--no-cache-dir` and cleaning the cash didn't work.

I installed `.whl` package through link in error text and installed it with pip install like: `pip install Werkzeug-0.11.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl` (in the same folder where it is downloaded).

After that everything worked with same `pip install` command that returned a error.

Comment: Maria, why? There is similar answer with another way of downloading a package above.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I've deleted my comment after re-reading your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```bash
rm -rf "$(pip cache dir)"
```

And if you're using conda:

```bash
conda clean --all
```

Answer (score 1):

The essential reason is that **the network is unstable**. When I change to a good network, I never get this error again.

In addition to replacing the network, there seem to be two other approaches:

1. Download the `.whl` file pointed by the url, then pip through `.whl`
2. Replace the open source mirror, then pip install

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

maybe pipiserver(where you pip install from) upload a pkg for example flask-1.0.0.tar.gz, and rm is upload a new flask-1.0.0.tag.gz,if new pkg code has changed ,the hash must be different,there is two ways:

1. installl an older pkg version =, `pip install flask==0.0.9`
2. wait new pkg release `flask==1.0.1` or cache expiration.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to clear pip cache with `-m pip cache purge` and using the `--no-cache-dir` argument but it was not helping.

In my case it was VPN being active during the attempts to install the package. As soon as I have turned it off everything worked as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install a package on my Raspberry Pi 5, and the dependency SymPy kept failing with this message. Deleting cache in any way mentioned above didn't help. I ended up downloading the source archive for SymPy (a .tar.gz file) from their GitHub page, and running:

```
pip install <archive_filename>
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me!

```
pip install --no-cache-dir flask --user
```

Answer (score -1):

If your pip is version 3 then you should try:
 `pip3 install <package name>`

Comment: As you are not providing a concrete answer and rather suggesting something, this should be a comment. Once you earn enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you'll be able to [comment everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)