# ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. when updating Django

Tags: django, pip

I have Django 2.2.7 and now I want to install Django 3.0.2. I read that I need to run the command `pip install -U Django` to update it, but when I try it shows this error message

```
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    Django from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/55/d1/8ade70e65fa157e1903fe4078305ca53b6819ab212d9fbbe5755afc8ea2e/Django-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=4f2c913303be4f874015993420bf0bd8fd2097a9c88e6b49c6a92f9bdd3fb13a:
        Expected sha256 4f2c913303be4f874015993420bf0bd8fd2097a9c88e6b49c6a92f9bdd3fb13a
             Got        f97dfd0d593c3c78e81ca2f4fd095a21cd0a30752e7b8754294bf1d42541a218
```

What should I do?

this is my requeriments.txt

```
argon2-cffi==19.2.0
asgiref==3.2.3
cffi==1.13.2
Django==3.0.2
django-environ==0.4.5
djangorestframework==3.11.0
Pillow==7.0.0
psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
pycparser==2.19
pytz==2019.3
six==1.14.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
```

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple different fixes:

Option 1:  Delete the PIP Cache Directory

**Unix**
~/.cache/pip and it respects the XDG_CACHE_HOME directory.

**macOS**
~/Library/Caches/pip

**Windows**
<CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA>\pip\Cache

Option 2:  Install and specify no cache directory:

pip install your-package --no-cache-dir

Comment: pip cache purge

Comment: This worked:  go to your pip cache dir and delete all:  del C:\Users\Your.Name\AppData\Local\pip\cache\*

Comment: running the `pip cache purge` worked for me when using pip-compile in a makefile

Answer (score 3):

This is pips integrated checking mechanism that is automatically checking the integrity of the downloaded package.

You can [check yourself](https://pypi.org/project/Django/#files) (by clicking `view` in the has column) that the sha256 of the `whl` file loaded from pypi should be

```
4f2c913303be4f874015993420bf0bd8fd2097a9c88e6b49c6a92f9bdd3fb13a
```

Your error suggests that you got

```
f97dfd0d593c3c78e81ca2f4fd095a21cd0a30752e7b8754294bf1d42541a218
```

So `pip` is (for security reasons) not installing the package for you. I would suggest to

- Check if `pip` is taking the `whl` from some `tmp` directory on your system with an incorrectly downloaded `whl` file sitting there - If so, try deleting it
- Check if you can install other packages without issues
- Try to manually download the `whl` file and then check the output of `pip hash <whl file>` (if it matches the `4f2c91330...` sha) and if you can do `pip install <whl file>`

Answer (score 0):

This issue fixed by change a network stable pypi mirror for me.

For example:
`pip config set global.index-url https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/pypi/web/simple`

Answer (score -1):

In addition to @FlyingTeller's answer, if it reads from a `requirements.txt` in `tmp` directory, instead of deleting it, you can try add your sha256 at the end.
eg:

```
--hash=sha256:f97dfd0d593c3c78e81ca2f4fd095a21cd0a30752e7b8754294bf1d42541a218
```

Comment: Got the following error:                                                                                                                                                       no such option: --hash  
pip install pandas --hash=sha256:5c54ea4ef3823108cd4ec7fb27ccba4c3a775e0f83e39c5e17f5094cb17748bc
no such option: --hash