# installing pycryptodome on Linux VM

Tags: linux, pip, pycryptodome

Im got ubuntu 18.04.4 VM and trying to install pycryptodome via

```
pip3 install pycryptodome
```

The error I get is
THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
pycryptodome

Ive tried clearing cache and upgrading pip but nothing has worked so far. What can I do to get rid of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens when there is an issue with the downloaded package. The following command downloads a new one and installs it.

`pip3 install pycryptodome --no-cache-dir`

Comment: That unfortunately gives me the same error

Comment: is it in an env?

Comment: if it is try this"pipenv clean" then "pipenv install <package>"

Comment: In the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183108/python-packages-hash-not-matching-whilst-installing-using-pip) i saw that this might help "rm ~/.cache/pip -rf"

Comment: was your issue solved in the end?