# pip install face_recognition got error hashes

Tags: python, pip

I try to install pip face_recognition in Raspberry Pi. I use virtual environment.

```
pip install face_recognition
```

But I got error

```
ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
    face-recognition-models>=0.3.0 from https://www.piwheels.org/simple/face-recognition-models/face_recognition_models-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#sha256=8d6b0af2e37a17120c3f13107974bc252142a4ffcb4e58eabdfcf26608e52c24 (from face_recognition):
        Expected sha256 8d6b0af2e37a17120c3f13107974bc252142a4ffcb4e58eabdfcf26608e52c24
             Got        b1e8b8472604b9a2f139e51d8413a0c31716d2e5887f07eb8ea84aee894c5890
```

I try to use --no-cache-dir, but still get same error

```
pip install --no-cache-dir face_recognition
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: [installing python packages have issue in md5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40400414)

Comment: add ur pip version